# Half the page + CSS alignment

Tags: css, alignment

I didn't know how to explain but draw a picture of the CSS align that I need.
The template has a fixed width and the green area represents the main content and blue division provides the title for that page.

The green `div` has the following css:

```
#content {
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This works great for the green box but I don't know how to make the blue section.
That `div` needs to cover the right side of the page + the entire width of the green area  as you can see from the picture below.

**Bear in mind that user can resize the window so the width of the blue bit cannot be fixed!**

How can I achieve this **using pure CSS**?

http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/3884/cssalign.png

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just like the picture !

Css :

```
#title{
   position:relative;
   width:50%;
   margin:50px 0 50px 50%;
   background:blue;
   padding:25px 245px;
   left:-490px;
}
#content{
     width:980px;
     height:600px; /* for it to work with no content */
     margin:0 auto;
     background:green;
}
```

Html :

```
<div id="title"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/sparkup/jL10axxv/

Comment: you didn't use the same shade of green and blue. -1 (j/k)

Comment: @Mark Down to poor lighting .)

Comment: Forget incorrect shades of color, even the proportions are totally messed up -1 :P (no really that was a +1)

Answer (score 0):

The basic outline: Give them both the same `left` position, give the green one whatever fixed width you want, and give the blue one `right: 0`.